# Comparing two ways to capture SQL statements in antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr4

What would be the difference between the following two ways to define a SQL script, which I've come across from a few existing grammar files:

```
root
   : stmtblock EOF
   ;

stmtblock
   : stmtmulti
   ;

stmtmulti
   : (stmt SEMI?)*
   ;

stmt 
   : selectstmt   // | or others ...
   ;
```

And:

```
root
   : stmtmulti EOF
   ;

stmtmulti
   : stmt*
   ;

stmt 
   : selectstmt ';' // | or others ...
   ;
```

It seems that:

- In the first version, the `SEMI` is pushed to the container statement, so it wouldn't have to be suffixed to every `stmt` alternation.
- In the first version, it also has a block that seems unnecessary at the top, namely, `stmtblock : stmtmulti ;`

Which of these two versions would be preferable and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that the first example treats the ‘;’ as optional (and not part of the `stmt` context.  The second example makes the ‘;’ a necessary part of the `stmt` and won’t match the rule without it being present.

Comment: would a better version be something like `stmtmulti: stmt (SEMI stmt)* SEMI?` ?

Comment: additionally, why do you think the first version has the `stmtblock : stmtmulti ;` in it?

Comment: `stmtmulti: stmt (SEMI stmt)* SEMI?` works if you want to require the ';' as a statement separator, and make it optional as a terminator (after the final statement)

Comment: `stmtblock : stmtmulti ;` is, admittedly, a bit odd.  It doesn't change anything with regard to what is recognized by the parser.  When you see it, it's either an artifact of someone being a bit "painfully literal" in transcribing a spec.  I've also run to cases where a rule that matches a single sub-rule was handy in doing code completion (it's a bit of a long story, so definitely more than a "comment"). Just realize that sometimes you'll modify a grammar just to make the resulting parseTree more useful for your purposes.